# AndroidX Camera Core ImageAnalysis.Analyser results in distorted image

Tags: google-cloud-storage, android-camera, androidx

I am using ImageAnalysis library to extract live previews to then barcode scanning and OCR on.

I'm not having any issues with barcode scanning at all, but OCR is resulting in some weak results. I'm sure this could be from a few reasons. My current attempt at working on the solution is to send the frames to GCP - Storage before I run OCR (or barcode) on the frames in order to look at them in bulk. All of them look very similar:

[image]

My best guess is the way i'm processing the frames could be causing the pixels to be organized in the buffer incorrectly (i'm inexperienced to Android - sorry). Meaning rather than organizing 0,0 then 0,1.....it's randomly taking pixels and putting them in random areas. I can't figure out where this is happening though. Once I can look at the image quality, then i'll be able to analyze what the issue is with OCR but this is my current blocker unfortunately.

Extra note: I am uploading the image to GCP - Storage prior to even running OCR, so for the sake of looking at this, we can ignore the OCR statement I made - I just wanted to give some background.

Below is the code where I initiate the camera and analyzer then observe the frames

```
private void startCamera() {
    //make sure there isn't another camera instance running before starting
    CameraX.unbindAll();

    /* start preview */
    int aspRatioW = txView.getWidth(); //get width of screen
    int aspRatioH = txView.getHeight(); //get height
    Rational asp = new Rational (aspRatioW, aspRatioH); //aspect ratio
    Size screen = new Size(aspRatioW, aspRatioH); //size of the screen

    //config obj for preview/viewfinder thingy.
    PreviewConfig pConfig = new PreviewConfig.Builder().setTargetResolution(screen).build();
    Preview preview = new Preview(pConfig); //lets build it

    preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener(
            new Preview.OnPreviewOutputUpdateListener() {
                //to update the surface texture we have to destroy it first, then re-add it
                @Override
                public void onUpdated(Preview.PreviewOutput output){
                    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) txView.getParent();
                    parent.removeView(txView);
                    parent.addView(txView, 0);

                    txView.setSurfaceTexture(output.getSurfaceTexture());
                    updateTransform();
                }
            });

    /* image capture */

    //config obj, selected capture mode
    ImageCaptureConfig imgCapConfig = new ImageCaptureConfig.Builder().setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CaptureMode.MAX_QUALITY)
            .setTargetRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()).build();
    final ImageCapture imgCap = new ImageCapture(imgCapConfig);

    findViewById(R.id.imgCapture).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("image taken", "image taken");
        }
    });

    /* image analyser */

    ImageAnalysisConfig imgAConfig = new ImageAnalysisConfig.Builder().setImageReaderMode(ImageAnalysis.ImageReaderMode.ACQUIRE_LATEST_IMAGE).build();
    ImageAnalysis analysis = new ImageAnalysis(imgAConfig);


    analysis.setAnalyzer(
            Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(), new ImageAnalysis.Analyzer(){
                @Override
                public void analyze(ImageProxy imageProxy, int degrees){
                    Log.d("analyze", "just analyzing");
                    if (imageProxy == null || imageProxy.getImage() == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    Image mediaImage = imageProxy.getImage();
                    int rotation = degreesToFirebaseRotation(degrees);
                    FirebaseVisionImage image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(toBitmap(mediaImage));


                    if (!isMachineLearning){
                        Log.d("analyze", "isMachineLearning is about to be true");
                        isMachineLearning = true;
                        String haha = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), toBitmap(mediaImage), "image" , "theImageDescription");
                        Log.d("uploadingimage: ", haha);
                        extractBarcode(image, toBitmap(mediaImage));
                    }
                }
            });

    //bind to lifecycle:
    CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, analysis, imgCap, preview);
}
```

Below is how I structure my detection (pretty straightforward and simple):

```
FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions options = new FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions.Builder()
            .setBarcodeFormats(FirebaseVisionBarcode.FORMAT_ALL_FORMATS)
            .build();

FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetector detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionBarcodeDetector(options);
detector.detectInImage(firebaseVisionImage)
```

Finally, when I'm uploading the image to GCP - Storage, this is what it looks like:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bmp being the image that I ran barcode scanning on - as well as OCR
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putBytes(data);
```

Thank you all for your kind help (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was trying to convert to a bitmap AFTER barcode scanning. The conversion wasn't properly written but I found a way around without having to write my own bitmap conversion function (though I plan on going back to it as I see myself needing it, and genuine curiosity wants me to figure it out)